# How to change data value when changing route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have problem with one thing with my navigation on website. When I'm in mobile mode and I expand my mobile menu everything is correct. But when I change the route the menu is still opened.

In `data()` i have declared `mobileNav`. I want to change it to false when I change the route. How can I achive that?

These are main method for displaying mobile nav.

```
 methods: {
    checkScreen() {
        this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (this.windowWidth <= 750) {
            this.mobile = true;
            return;
        }
        this.mobile = false;
        this.mobileNav = false;
        return;
    },
    toggleMobileNav() {
        this.mobileNav = !this.mobileNav;
    }
},
```

Comment: As of right now, the issue is not reproducible. Rather than providing us with 2 lines of text, please make the effort of creating a [repro].

Comment: This is simple as that. I just want to change the value of mobileNav when I change the route.

Comment: Then, use `watch` with a `$route` dependency, and drop in a `this.mobileNav = 'worked'` there. Works perfectly fine on a given approach. Depends how you have written yours.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the router after hook?

```js
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  this.mobileNav = false;
})
```

reference: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks